# How to create mean+-sd data.frame?

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I hope create (mean ± sd ) form.
below is example code

```
a=c("type","A","B","C")
b=c("a","a","b","b")
c=c(22, 32, 23, 20)
d=c(12,25,23,30)
e=c(15,17,23,35)
f=data.frame(b,c,d,e)
colnames(f)=a
```

new table component mean ± sd is by type.
like this ..

```
type A B C 
a  mean ± sd .. mean ± sd 
b  mean ± sd .. mean ± sd
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'type' and use `summarise_all`.  Assuming that we want to add and subtract the `mean` and `sd` and get the summarised columns

```
library(dplyr)
f %>%
   group_by(type) %>% 
   summarise_all(funs(mean(.) + round(sd(.), 2), mean(.)- round(sd(.), 2)))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#    type `A_+` `B_+` `C_+` `A_-` `B_-` `C_-`
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      a 34.07 27.69 17.41 19.93  9.31 14.59
#2      b 23.62 31.45 37.49 19.38 21.55 20.51
```

---

If this is needed as a `character` class

```
f %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(paste(mean(.), round(sd(.), 2), sep=" ± ")))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#    type           A           B         C
#   <fctr>       <chr>       <chr>     <chr>
#1      a   27 ± 7.07 18.5 ± 9.19 16 ± 1.41
#2      b 21.5 ± 2.12 26.5 ± 4.95 29 ± 8.49
```

Comment: thanks but, i really want form is "20 ± 0.5" for paper. one cell apperance "mean ± sd"

Comment: @SungminYang  Updated with second option.  Please check